# DWM broken after dd on Arch Linux

Tags: arch-linux, dd, dwm

I have been trying to take a backup/copy of my GPT disk on one computer and then restore it on another.

When I start the new computer, it seems as though the Arch Linux part of it is running fine, but as soon as I start DWM through X, it gives me a black screen with the cursor in the middle. When I try to start a terminal, st, it just freezes. The X log doesn't give any errors.

**The way I tried it**

I have made a copy of the partition table with fdisk and images of all my individual partitions with *`dd`*. Then on the other computer, I restore the partition table and then restore the partitions with:

```
dd if=/mnt/partition1.img of=/dev/sdx1 bs=4096 status=progress && sync
```

Then repeat for the 4 partitions. I even remount all the partitions and make a new fstab file and reinstall grub and redo `grub.cfg`.

I have 1 EFI partition, 1 swap partition and 2 partitions for the system, but everything gets installed in one of them.

*Extra:*

The disk I am copying from is 1TB and the one I am backing up to only 512GB so I can't do a disk backup with dd (afaik).

Comment: Could you provide the output of `df -h` so we can see how big your individual partitions are ? Also, what graphics cards are both systems using ? I suspect they differ ...

Comment: The nice thing about GPT and UEFI is that everything is in a file. There are no magical blocks outside or inside partitions. Instead of dealing with images created with `dd`, you can create partitions on the new disk that correspond to the old disk partitions, create file systems on the partitions, and then copy the files from the old disk to the new disk. You can use `tar` for this. One thing you will have to watch out for are UUIDs, if the partitions or file systems are referenced using UUIDs in `/etc/fstab`.

Comment: @JohanMyréen That is actually what I tried to do. Would you just tar the root folder of the partitions and then move them over? I will just recreate the fstab that is no problem 

Comment: @thecarpy How does the graphic card affect DWM?

Comment: @MathiasEgekvist Yes, copy the files with tar. You will have to do this as root, so that tar can set the correct modes and ownership on the files.